# What's the 日本語 equivalent of saying "That's none of your business"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What's the Japanese equivalent of saying "None of your business", or "None of your concern"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my feeling and personal experience "it's none of your business" is just one of those sentences you don't hear that often in Japan most likely because it's quite direct and (kind of) offensive. And as you know Japanese people tend to avoid this generally.

That being said (and I might be wrong), it doesn't mean there is no way to say it.

According to [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/it%27s+none+of+your+business) and to a native speaker I just asked to the closest translation is:

> 余計なお世話だ

In the sample sentences you can also find いらぬお世話だ and 大きに御世話だ **(*)** but the first one I quoted above is translated as "none of your business" also by my dictionary as a whole.

Probably another, more literal, way to say it would be: あなたには関係ないことだ。

Not being a native speaker it's hard to say which one of these would be more natural and more commonly used though. As I said I believe the first one,  but maybe someone can leave a comment.

PS. Related to what I said in the beginning, it is interesting to notice how in Japanese the literal translation is totally different. In fact, literally it is like "(it is) an excess of favor/assistance (on your side)". If you think about it this is very much in line with the Japanese way of saying things indirectly. They are not telling you that something is not your business, they are telling you that you are "minding too much" implying between the lines that.. it's not your business. :)

I thought it could be interesting to add this (personal) interpretation as a more "cultural" note.

**(*)** *Note in the comment that at this point it seems unclear if the correct form
 is 大きに御世話だ (as in the reference weblio) or 大きな御世話だ (as Naruto pointed out).*

Comment: 大きに御世話だ should be a typo for 大き**な**お世話だ (although it seems to be a mistake on the JMdict's side...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the answer (it sounded a little strange indeed).

Comment: I don't think 大きにお世話だ is a mistake. Saw it being used in print and heard it with my own ears, but never with 大きな...

Comment: Really? In view of this comment maybe I'll edit the answer again just to point out that this is not clear yet.

Comment: おおきに in 大きに御世話だ is correct.  おおきに or おほきに【大{おお}きに】is a 連用形 form of 形容動詞「おおき（なり）」, which means 非常{ひじょう}に, はなはだ, 大{おお}いに, also which means *Thanks!* mainly used in the Kansai district. The ehymology of the meaning of *Thanks!* is **大{おおき}に有{あり}難{がた}し** which means *Thank you very much* or  literally *very much difficult to happen or exist*.  As you know, 有{あり}難{がた}し is omitted from the original phrase leaving 大{おおき}に and the original meaning *thank you*. And the omitted part remains as **ありがとう** in the standard Japanese meaning *Thanks*!

Comment: 「大き**に**お世話だ」の用例はだいたいどれもちょっと古そうな感じがします・・ちょっと古い小説とか。。→　https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E4%B8%96%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%A0%22&oq=%22%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E4%B8%96%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%A0%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Chocolate: Yes, I think it's an old-fashioned expression, too. And I don't think 大｛おおき｝にお世話だ is a suitable interpretation for *None of your business!*, but I would like to say the expression is originally correct and need not be amended to 大きなお世話だ.

Answer (score 9):

> In my feeling and personal experience "it's none of your business" is just one of those sentences you don't hear that often in Japan most likely because it's quite direct and (kind of) offensive. And as you know Japanese people tend to avoid this generally.   　
>   <**from Tommy's answer**>

We don't say this kind of direct phrase to others usually in Japan, but you can hear the phrase like "None of your business", or "None of your concern" in a family.

Boys and girls at a rebellious age sometimes would say towards their parents 放｛ほ｝っといて！ or 放｛ほ｝っといてよ！when their parents try to be concerned about their children.

放っといて is pronounced ほっといて *hottoite* or ほうっといて *hoottoite*, and formally it is said 放｛ほう｝って置｛お｝いて, which means *"Leave me alone"*.

Even in Japan, a strong-minded woman may sometimes say flatly or even **with a pretended gracious manner** to the same sex opponents usually in her work place; 放｛ほ｝っといてくれる, 放｛ほ｝っといてくれますか or 放｛ほ｝っといてください, besides 邪魔｛じゃま｝しないで or 構｛かま｝わないでくれる meaning *It's none of your business*.
　　
[image]

Comment: I think that these phrases may accomplish a similar effect, but are not similar enough in meaning to what the question asked for.

Comment: @Kurausukun: You are right. But it is also true that there is not exact Japanese interpretation for this phrase. Then the questioner have to guess the equivalent phrase by judging the answers if the answerers including me do not intend to tell a lie, and/or have to double-check the proposed answers by means of other materials.

Comment: @Kurausukun: I think if there is not exact equivalent phrase, which is literally translated from, to the original one, it is the best one when the new phrase has the nearest same effect in the same situation.

Comment: Gonna accept Tommy's, but your's is just as good; tho, not as on topic to warrant being marked an answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah I also up-voted this as it gives a nice insight on common situations where you might hear something with a similar meaning (and it also kinda confirms my original guess). In my answer I tried to keep it more "literal".

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention the context, but if you're among close friends (or maybe if said jokingly at a drinking party to be funny) you could say:

お前関係ないだろ！

Omae kankei nai daro!

A word of caution: under no circumstances should you say the above in a formal situation or when addressing people you are not close to.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I think あなたにはかんけいないです or あなたにはかんけいのないことです are pretty good substitutes. 余計なお世話 is similar, but in my opinion, it doesn't quite have the same nuance; I feel like 余計なお世話 means something more along the lines of "you're sticking your nose in where it doesn't belong," or "nobody asked you to do this, so keep out of it." On the other hand, かんけいない really does have a similar meaning to the English phrase--"It has nothing to do with you" is a pretty literal translation of it, so you can see why it works pretty well. It should go without saying that you should be very careful if you actually plan to say these things to people, and you should consider whether or not to say them at all.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple common phrases:

余計{よけい} なことするな。

君{きみ}の知{し}ったことじゃないよ。

For future reference, for common phrases like this, if you go to jisho.org, select the "Sentences" tab and plug in the word/phrase, you will typically get a variety of sentences showing different ways of saying the word/phrase you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese, there is a way to express "none of your concern" at *least* offensive tone yet send through a strong meaning of not to meddle with someone's else issue.

> あなたには 関わりのない事です。
>
> [The issue] has nothing to do with you;
>
> You have no relation with this [issue].

The word `関わり` means relation or connection (the verb counterpart is `関わる`). So when the word is negated, `関わり` (in relation) becomes `関わりのない` (no relation).

The sentence can be expressed with neutral or serious tone, depending on the speaker expression and status quo. There are some variations that may be heard likewise.

> あなたとは なんの関わりが ございません。
>
> 君とは 関わりのない事だ。

Because it holds such a strong meaning, the sentence is usually used between strangers and people with relationship gap. One shall *not* use these sentences against good friends.

**References**

- [関わり on Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E9%96%A2%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A)
- [係わり・関わり on コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BF%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%83%BB%E9%96%A2%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A-226869)
- [関わり on Weblio辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%96%A2%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has said it yet, I would point out that the word 迷惑 also has some of the implications of the English. Although it's more often used to mean "making a nuisance of yourself" generically, rather than trying to solve other people's problems specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Other very modest expressions for the person:

ご[心配]{しんぱい}には[及]{およ}びません: It's not the case you mind.

Comment: But... "None of your business!" or "Mind your own business!" is not a modest expression, is it...?